# Place checkboxes on a horizontal rule with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to create a web-based rating scale with seven checkboxes, two text labels and a horizontal rule in the background. It should look similar to a [paper-based rating scale](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Example_Likert_Scale.svg). In addition, I would like to mark the middle checkbox by a short vertical rule.

Because checkboxes seem to be quite difficult to style, I replaced them by a text symbol and a border in the labels. I manually positioned these checkboxes and the vertical rule on the horizontal rule. The result looks ok in Firefox but it doesn't seem to work for other browsers. In Chrome, IE and Edge, the vertical line is not placed in the center of the scale. Additionally, the checkbox symbol is not centered in Chrome.

Is there a better way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/tzuyya36/1/

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  font: 12px/16px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "\00a0";
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #8b8d8e;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
  -moz-border-radius: 999px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
  content: "\26ab";
}

label.scale1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
}

label.scale2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 82px;
}

label.scale3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 172px;
}

label.scale4 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 262px;
}

label.scale5 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 352px;
}

label.scale6 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 442px;
}

label.scale7 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 532px;
}

div.scale {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 540px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

div.leftLabel {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -120px;
}

div.rightLabel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 560px;
}

hr.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #8b8d8e;
}

hr.vertical {
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 257px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  border: 2px solid #8b8d8e;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="scale">
    <hr class="horizontal">
    <hr class="vertical">
    <div class="leftLabel">low</div>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test1" value="1"><label for="test1" class="scale1"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test2" value="2"><label for="test2" class="scale2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test3" value="3"><label for="test3" class="scale3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test4" value="4"><label for="test4" class="scale4"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test5" value="5"><label for="test5" class="scale5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test6" value="6"><label for="test6" class="scale6"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test7" value="7"><label for="test7" class="scale7"></label>
    <div class="rightLabel">high</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a symbol which may change in appearance depending on operating system, font etc. I would use another pseudo element. This way you have complete control over the appearance.

To centre the vertical line you would use `left: 50%`, this way the width of parent is irrelevant, and `margin-left: -15px`, half the width of the element.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  font: 12px/16px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "\00a0";
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #8b8d8e;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
  -moz-border-radius: 999px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

label.scale1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
}

label.scale2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 82px;
}

label.scale3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 172px;
}

label.scale4 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 262px;
}

label.scale5 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 352px;
}

label.scale6 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 442px;
}

label.scale7 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 532px;
}

div.scale {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 540px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

div.leftLabel {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -120px;
}

div.rightLabel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 560px;
}

hr.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #8b8d8e;
}

hr.vertical {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #8b8d8e;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="scale">
    <hr class="horizontal">
    <hr class="vertical">
    <div class="leftLabel">low</div>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test1" value="1"><label for="test1" class="scale1"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test2" value="2"><label for="test2" class="scale2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test3" value="3"><label for="test3" class="scale3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test4" value="4"><label for="test4" class="scale4"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test5" value="5"><label for="test5" class="scale5"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test6" value="6"><label for="test6" class="scale6"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test7" value="7"><label for="test7" class="scale7"></label>
    <div class="rightLabel">high</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, thank you. But it seems like I haven't positioned the checkboxes correctly. At least in Firefox the middle one is not centered.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Looks OK to me in Firefox, though I'm on Mac. Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, this is how it looks for me on a Windows machine in Firefox: https://postimg.org/image/n3h61si91/

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps Firefox isn't taking the rotation of the element in to account. How does the updated snippet look?

Comment: Ok, this seems to work much better. The vertical rule is shifted slightly upwards but I could live with that: https://postimg.org/image/z6mhpmgj9/

Answer (score 1):

because I like flex, box shadows & gradients.

This way you can add as many inputs you want and the layout will adapt.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

form > div {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.scale {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* Centering the labels */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Adding the background gray line */
  background:linear-gradient(transparent 45%, gray 45%, gray 55%, transparent 55%);
  position: relative;
}

/* vertical rule */
.scale::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  background: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}

input {
  display:none;
}

/* Direct styling of the labels as UTF8 icons can be inconsistent across browsers */
label{
  display:block;
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

input:checked+label {
  /* Inset box-shadows can be used to create additional borders */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <div>low</div>

  <div class="scale">
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test1"><label for="test1"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test2" checked><label for="test2"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test3"><label for="test3"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test4"><label for="test4"></label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="test5"><label for="test5"></label>
  </div>
  
  <div>high</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks very good in Firefox, Chrome and Edge but in IE, the checkboxes are somehow shifted to the right (tested with IE 11).

Comment: The default styles are not always consistent between browsers. Check that there is no default margin, padding or that the width is ok. You can also use normalize.css to limit this kind of problem

Comment: I really love the flexibility of this approach but I cannot make it work in IE. It adds some additional spacing to the left: https://postimg.org/image/t464qieol/ Adjusting margin and padding or including normalize.css didn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use hard-coded `pixel` values, use `%` here as they are uniformly distributed.
2. Make 3 divisions. Left label, right label and middle scale. Middle scale is the main focus and left right labels can be done separately.

```css
.scaleContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

div.horizontal {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
}

div.vertical {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: calc(100% * 0 / 6)
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: calc(100% * 1 / 6)
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: calc(100% * 2 / 6)
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: calc(100% * 3 / 6)
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: calc(100% * 4 / 6)
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: calc(100% * 5 / 6)
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(7) {
  left: calc(100% * 6 / 6)
}

.scale>div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.scale>div:first-child,
.scale>div:last-child {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="scale">
    <div class="leftLabel">low</div>
    <div class="scaleContainer">
      <div class="horizontal"></div>
      <div class="vertical"></div>
      <input type="radio" value="1">
      <input type="radio" value="2">
      <input type="radio" value="3">
      <input type="radio" value="4">
      <input type="radio" value="5">
      <input type="radio" value="6">
      <input type="radio" value="7">
    </div>
    <div class="rightLabel">high</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly well in Firefox, Chrome and Edge. In IE, the middle section with the scale is not aligned with the labels (tested with IE 11).